# How to store a BeautifulSoup object into a dataframe as one single string in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML document (its a 10-K filing from Apple), which I would like to store in one single pandas dataframe column as a string with readable content. Therefore, I so far used BeautifulSoup to translate the HTML document into a "readable" text. By using the get_text() function, I am so far able to print the text in a readable format, however I am not able to store this text as a string being able to be inserted in a dataframe.

This is the format I am looking for:

| Ticker | 10-K |
| --- | --- |
| AAPL | Apple Inc. builds Macs ... |

Here my thoughts so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

file = open("filing-details.html", "r")
soup = BeautifulSoup(file)
#print(soup.get_text()) gives me an output in a readable form, such as "Apple Inc. builds Macs"
print(soup.get_text())
```

Now, I would like to store this generated string "Apple Inc. builds Macs", so that I can insert it to a dataframe. Therefore, I tried this:

```
text = soup.get_text()
df1["txt"] = text
df1
```

However, this gives me the following output:

| Ticker | 10-K |
| --- | --- |
| AAPL | \n10-K\n1\na10-k20179302017.htm\n10-K\n\n\n\n... |

I also tried the following, but received the same result:

```
df1["txt"] = str(soup.get_text())
```

Does somebody know, how I can store the exact same output I receive by using print(soup.get_text()) as a string in a dataframe? (the dataframe is later used for textual analysis)

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does the`html` file look like?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a dictionary with title as key and data text as value and convert them into DataFrame.

```
    new_data={
        "Ticker":['AAPL',...],
        "10-K":['soup.get_text()',...]
    }
    df = pandas.DataFrame(new_data)
```

#list of values is optional, required only if there are more data

try this method and please reply if it worked